# How to hide all tabs (local tasks) except the user account tabs?

Tags: theming, 8

I want to hide all tabs (local tasks) for non-admin users except the tabs on the user account page (for example, I want to hide tabs on nodes of all content types).

To hide the tabs, I added a check for admin permission in my theme template: `templates/menu/menu-local-tasks.html.twig`

```
{% if user.hasPermission('administer nodes') %}
  {% if primary %}
    <h2 class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Primary tabs'|t }}</h2>
    <ul class="tabs--primary nav nav-tabs">{{ primary }}</ul>
  {% endif %}
  {% if secondary %}
    <h2 class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Secondary tabs'|t }}</h2>
    <ul class="tabs--secondary pagination pagination-sm">{{ secondary }}</ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

This works, but it hides the tabs on the user account page as well.

I tried to find a more specific template of `menu-local-tasks` for the user account. I turned on twig debugging, but these were the suggestions:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--mytheme-local-tasks.html.twig
   x block--local-tasks-block.html.twig
   * block--core.html.twig
   * block.html.twig
-->
```

All of these affect the entire site; there is no way to target just the user account local tasks.

Is there a way to do this with theme templates?  I chose this approach rather than trying to unset the local tasks in a hook because in a template you can do it in just a line or two of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend not doing this by code, this can be achieved using built-in configuration settings, by using a second block with proper rules. Try this:

1. Go to `Structure > Block layout`
2. Select your theme
3. Place a second tabs block where-ever you want it
4. Limit the visibility on the block fitting your requirements

   - Most likely limit `Pages` to something like `user/*`
   - and by `Roles`, e.g. `Authenticated user`
   - (remember that administrators are authenticated users too, so you might need more specific roles to to prevent admins seeing tabs block twice; or add the "hide"-option on user-pages for the first, original tabs block )

Comment: I totally forgot that tabs were a block in D8.  Best way to configure the `Pages` is to use `/user/*` on the "user tabs" and `NOT /user/*` on the "original tabs"; that way, you don't need to set roles.

Comment: Also note I had to change the theme file name to be more specific: `block--mytheme-local-tasks.html.twig`